# Logging in webMethods CAF

Tags: webmethods, webmethods-caf

Is it possible to log smartly in CAF application?

What is not smart is to use `log()` method from `com.webmethods.caf.faces.bean.BaseFacesBean`, beause it logs as jsf logger, so it shares configuration for logging with other things in jsf - it's not application specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible when you modify `log4j.init.properties` file in `${MWS_HOME}/server/default/config` folder.

When you publish your CAF application from designer - there is new category created. When you log in as `sysadmin` user and you open `Logging Configuration link`:

[image: webMethods MWS > Logging Configuration link (sysadmin)]

there is new category added (I added cafTestApplication):

[image: Logging Configuration detail]

In you CAF application Java, you can get Logger as:

```java
private static org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("/caftestapplication");
```

Note: category is in lower case (it was changed by MWS)

All you need to use different log (and not `_full_.log`) is to add this (MWS restart needed):

```
log4j.category./caftestapplication=DEBUG,newLogFile

log4j.appender.newLogFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.newLogFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.newLogFile.File=${log4j.logging.dir}/newLogFile.log
log4j.appender.newLogFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.newLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern=${log4j.message.pattern}
```

And now all your logging messages are in new `newLogFile.log` which is in same folder as `_full_.log`.

Comment: Upvoting for answering yourself :)